# Converting cloud-init logs to json using a script

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, bash

I am trying to convert the cloud-init logs to json,  so that the filebeat can pick it up and send it to the Kibana. I want to do this by using a shell script or python script. Is there any script that converts such logs to json?

My python script is below

```
import json
import subprocess

filename = "/home/umesh/Downloads/scripts/cloud-init.log"

def convert_to_json_log(line):
    """ convert each line to json format """
    log = {}
    log['msg'] = line
    log['logger-name'] = 'cloud-init'
    log['ServiceName'] = 'Contentprocessing'
    return json.dumps(log)


def log_as_json(filename):    
    f = subprocess.Popen(['cat','-F',filename],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        line = f.stdout.readline()
        log = convert_to_json_log(line) 
        print log
        with open("/home/umesh/Downloads/outputs/cloud-init-json.log", 'a') as new:
            new.write(log + '\n')

log_as_json(filename)
```

The scripts returns a file with json format, but the msg filed returns empty string. I want to convert each line of the log as message string.

Comment: please, fix indents in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try reading the raw log file using python inbuilt functions rather than running `os` commands using subprocess, because:

- It will be more portable (work across OS'es)
- Faster and less prone to errors

Re-writing your `log_as_json` function as follows worked for me:

```
inputfile = "cloud-init.log"
outputfile = "cloud-init-json.log"

def log_as_json(filename):
    # Open cloud-init log file for reading
    with open(inputfile, 'r') as log:
        # Open the output file to append json entries
        with open(outputfile, 'a') as jsonlog:
            # Read line by line
            for line in log.readlines():
                # Convert to json and write to file
                jsonlog.write(convert_to_json(line)+"\n")
```

Comment: Thanks rahoogan. This is the exact what i have also wrote.

Answer (score 0):

After taking some time on preparing the customised script finally i made the below script. It might be helpful to many others.

```
  import json

def convert_to_json_log(line):
    """ convert each line to json format """
    log = {}
    log['msg'] = json.dumps(line)
    log['logger-name'] = 'cloud-init'
    log['serviceName'] = 'content-processing'
    return json.dumps(log)

# Open the file with read only permit

f = open('/var/log/cloud-init.log', "r")

# use readlines to read all lines in the file

# The variable "lines" is a list containing all lines in the file

lines = f.readlines()

# close the file after reading the lines.
f.close()

jsonData = ''
for line in lines:
    jsonLine = convert_to_json_log(line)
    jsonData = jsonData + "\n" + jsonLine;


with open("/var/log/cloud-init/cloud-init-json.log", 'w') as new:
    new.write(jsonData)
```